# How to map errors to the field?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

Below is my server side validation in lumen :

```
$rules = array(
            'prog_code' => 'required',
            'payer_id' => 'required',
        );
        $validator = \Validator::make($post, $rules);
        if (!$validator->fails()) {
            try {
                // Start Logic Here
            } catch (\Exception $e) {

            }
        } else {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return response()->json($errors->all());
        }
```

and it return error like below :

```
[
    "The prog code field is required.",
    "The payer id field is required.",
]
```

but the problem is how I map the error of which field because I want to show the error below the particular text field.

**Can we customize error like below :**

```
[
        [prog_code] => "The prog code field is required.",
        [payer_id] => "The payer id field is required.",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieve the same response was to do:

```
if ( $validator->fails() ) {
  $errors = [];

  foreach ( $validator->errors()->toArray() as $field => $message ) {
    $errors[$field] = $message[0];
  }

  return response()->json($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dump the `$errors` variable you have an array of errors like your target:

```
ViewErrorBag {#406
  #bags: array:1 [
    "default" => MessageBag {#407
      #messages: array:1 [
        "pin" => array:1 [
          0 => "The Programming Code is required Sir!"
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

`$errors` variable is injected by validator when there are errors

Comment: not working man.. It's giving same error summery that how I don't.

Comment: Just pasted a working example from a production project how is it not working? clear your cache or something

Comment: Its working fine .. its validating as well . but my question is different .. plz read my above question once.

Comment: Maybe you can do: 'prog_code.required' => json_encode(['prog_code' =>  'The Programming Code is required Sir!']),